# What happens if you go to that specific place before fighting Gebel?

Tags: bloodstained-ritual-of-the-night

So in order to get the good ending, you'll have to do a lot of stuff to

> get Zangetsu's sword to be able to strike Gremory during Gebel's fight when the moon turns red.

However, earlier in the game, you can see

> the red moon

in the Garden of Silence. In fact, it's where you have to go after the Gebel fight. So I was wondering... what happens if you go there

> right after you got Zangetsu's sword? Can you slice the red moon just like you're supposed to after fighting Gebel?

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3):

If you visit that room during the time you mentioned

> the moon is mysteriously missing.

Comment: I actually tried this the first time I played that game, which is how I know this.

Comment: I checked this out on my second playthrough, and man was finding that a disappointing cop-out.